# check the checkbox if the data is same with database

Tags: php, html, explode, checked

Cannot find out what problems,for example at the beginning i add patient details, i selected allergies and asthma and store into database,but i want to edit the details, it only checked asthma (last value)...please help me find out the answer Thank you.

```
<tr>
<td>Past Medical Records</td>
<td><?php 
    $DiseaseSplit = $medicalRec['Diseases'];
    $array = explode(", ",$DiseaseSplit);
    foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo "<li>$item</li>";
}
?></td></tr>
<tr><label class="q" for="q1"></label>    
<td><input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="NONE" <?php if($item == "NONE") { echo 'checked=\"checked\"';}?>>None</td></tr>

<tr>
<td><input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="ALLERGIES" <?php if($item == "ALLERGIES") { echo 'checked=\"checked\"';}?>>Allergies</td>
<td align="left"><input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="BLOOD DYSCRASIAS" <?php if($item == "BLOOD DYSCRASIAS") { echo 'checked=\"checked\"';}?>>Blood Dyscrasias</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting `$item` for every iteration of the loop.

I would try making a hash map to see which values should be shown/hidden:

```
<tr>
<td>Past Medical Records</td>
<td><?php 
    $data = array();        

    $DiseaseSplit = $medicalRec['Diseases'];
    $array = explode(", ",$DiseaseSplit);
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $data[$item] = true;
        echo "<li>$item</li>";
    }
?></td></tr>
<tr><label class="q" for="q1"></label>    
<td><input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="NONE" <?php if(isset($data["NONE"])) { echo 'checked=\"checked\"';}?>>None</td></tr>

<tr>
<td><input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="ALLERGIES" <?php if(isset($data["ALLERGIES"])) { echo 'checked=\"checked\"';}?>>Allergies</td>
<td align="left"><input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="BLOOD DYSCRASIAS" <?php if(isset($data["BLOOD DYSCRASIAS"])) { echo 'checked=\"checked\"';}?>>Blood Dyscrasias</td></tr>
```